# Drag-and-drop element to specific position - Selenium, WebDriverJS

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, jasmine

I am trying to create a test with `Selenium`, `WebDriverJS` and `Jasmine` to verify that whenever a `li` element is moved right with a *drag-and-drop* selection, it should not be displayed anymore. This is the snippet of my code:

```
it('should make the card disappear when the UI is swiped right', function() {
    var card1 = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('.slide:nth-last-child(1)'));
    var card1Move = driver.executeScript('arguments[0].setAttribute("style", "right:250px")', card1);
    driver.actions()
        .mouseMove(card1)
        .mouseDown()
        .mouseMove(card1Move)
        .mouseUp()
        .perform();
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('.slide:nth-last-child(1)')).isDisplayed()
        .then(function(elem) {
            expect(elem).toBe(false);
        });
})
```

The function appear to be working, but I get the following error:

```
Failures:
    1) Swiping method should make the card disappear when the UI is swiped right

Message:
    TypeError: location.getRawId is not a function
Stack:
    TypeError: location.getRawId is not a function
    at webdriver.ActionSequence.mouseMove (/Users/.../node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/actionsequence.js:108:46)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../tests/index.js:27:14)
```

According to the test, the error is in the `.mouseMove(card1Move)` method.
Do you know what is causing this issue and a possible way to solve it? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: Is it reproduced in different browsers? Could you also post the complete error traceback? Thanks.

Comment: Just in Firefox. Sure! I have just updated it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `mouseMove(card1Move)` with `mouseMove({x: offsetFromCenter, y: offsetFromCenter})`

e.g. `mouseMove({x: 100, y: 0})` will move 100px to the right of card1's center.

Comment: How can I implement using php webdriver?
https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver

Answer (score 2):

Currently you can also do

```
.dragAndDrop(card1, { x: 100, y: 0 })
```

which does exactly this  - `mouseDown(element).mouseMove(location).mouseUp()`

see [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/actions.js#L262)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in protractor "Failed: location.getRawId is not a function" - my issue was that the element I was searching was not to be found.

Comment: true, same here